# How to print complete row from excel Sheet using python pandas from user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I asked the same question but it is closed and I am not clear with that answer so I am asking again.

I have an excel file similar to this:

[image]

Above is the attached picture to see what the excel sheet looks like.

I am learning to write a program if the user input "Martin" it should displays the entire row.

Still learning the basics. Can someone help me how to display the entire row using user input?

below is the code which is not giving output or error.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

student = pd.read_excel("student.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")

i = input("enter store number: ")

found = []

for letter in i:
    if letter in student:
        if letter not in found:
            found.append(letter)
for student in found:
    print(student)
```

Comment: `print(student[student['Name']==i])`

Comment: Side note: no screenshots of code please.

Comment: @BigBen i replaced print (student) with your condition, same issue no output or error

Comment: Get rid of everything after `i = input("enter store number: ")` and then add `print(student[student['Name']==i])`.

Comment: enter store number: Martin
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, City, Marks, Rank]
Index: []

Comment: Maybe it'd help if you created a [good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) with sample data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are trying to a select the rows where your column value = input. This is the best way to do that :)

```
import pandas as pd
import os

student = pd.read_excel("student.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")

i = input("enter store number: ")
print(student[student['Name'] == i])
```

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, City, Marks, Rank]
Index: []

Comment: above is the output i am getting

Comment: If you are not using a input that matches your values in the name column you might get an empty df in the results

Comment: enter store number: Martin
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, City, Marks, Rank]
Index: []

Comment: i am using the value within the column  but not getting expected output

Comment: Okay try using i.strip() instead of just i in the last line.

Comment: after adding i.strip() in print(student[student['Name'] == i.strip()]) no change

Comment: print(student) and see if there is any data in it

Comment: if i print, print(student) it is giving complete excel sheet data.

Comment: print(student[student['Name'].str.strip() == i.strip()]) you can try this but if this doesn't work then there is some encoding issue in your excel sheet